# Python in enumerate not giving expected output

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm having an issue with output from in enumerate function. It is adding parenthesis and commas into the data. I'm trying to use the list for a comparison loop. Can anyone tell me why the special characters are added resembling tuples? I'm going crazy here trying to finish this but this bug is causing issues.

```
# Pandas is a software library written for the Python programming language for data manipulation and analysis.
import pandas as pd
#NumPy is a library for the Python programming language, adding support for large, multi-dimensional arrays and matrices, along with a large collection of high-level mathematical functions to operate on these arrays
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv("https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/dataset_part_1.csv")
df.head(10)
df.isnull().sum()/df.count()*100
df.dtypes
# Apply value_counts() on column LaunchSite
df[['LaunchSite']].value_counts()
# Apply value_counts on Orbit column
df[['Orbit']].value_counts()
 #landing_outcomes = values on Outcome column
landing_outcomes = df[['Outcome']].value_counts()
print(landing_outcomes)

#following causes data issue
for i,outcome in enumerate(landing_outcomes.keys()):
    print(i,outcome)

#following also causes an issue to the data
bad_outcomes=set(landing_outcomes.keys()[[1,3,5,6,7]])
bad_outcomes

# landing_class = 0 if bad_outcome
# landing_class = 1 otherwise
landing_class = []
for value in df['Outcome'].items():
    if value in bad_outcomes:
        landing_class.append(0)
    else:
        landing_class.append(1)
df['Class']=landing_class
df[['Class']].head(8)
df.head(5)
df["Class"].mean()
```

The issue I'm having is

```
for i,outcome in enumerate(landing_outcomes.keys()):
    print(i,outcome)
```

is changing my data and giving an output of

```
0 ('True ASDS',)
1 ('None None',)
2 ('True RTLS',)
3 ('False ASDS',)
4 ('True Ocean',)
5 ('False Ocean',)
6 ('None ASDS',)
7 ('False RTLS',)
```

additionally, when I run

```
bad_outcomes=set(landing_outcomes.keys()[[1,3,5,6,7]])
bad_outcomes
```

my output is

```
{('False ASDS',),
 ('False Ocean',),
 ('False RTLS',),
 ('None ASDS',),
 ('None None',)}
```

I do not understand why my data return is far from expected and how to correct it.

Comment: Because the values *are* tuples?! Not much to do with `enumerate`.

Comment: What's  the expected output?

Comment: @deceze, am I reading it wrong as several tuples?  I was expecting it to be in a list, but additionally comparison of df value to bad_outcomes object is giving all 0's, meaning all are false when that is not correct.

Comment: Well, what do you get if you remove `enumerate`? Probably tuples as well, no? So this is about `landing_outcomes.keys()`, not `enumerate`. So it's a [tag:pandas] question. Focus on that if you want to attract people who can help you.

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Changing my code to: 
for i,outcome in enumerate(landing_outcomes.keys()):
    print(i,outcome[0]) 
fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for i, (outcome,) in enumerate(landing_outcomes.keys()):
    print(i, outcome)
```

Or

```
for i, outcome in enumerate(landing_outcomes.keys()):
    print(i, outcome[0])
```